# Is returning Double.NaN from method a good practice to indicate invalid double value

Tags: java

Currently, I'm implementing a method with the following signature

`public static double Newtons_method(double[] payments, double[] days, double guess)`

Sometimes, the calculation will fail. There are several ways to indicate failure.

1. Change returned type to `Double`, and return as null.
2. Throws exception.
3. Return `Double.NaN` and use `Double.isNaN(double)` to test against it.

However, there are several concern.

1. I prefer not to return Object, for performance purpose. I need to do a lot of box and unboxing if `Double` is used.
2. I prefer not to throw an exception, for performance purpose. Also, `try` `catch` makes code looks messy. Not, in `Newtons_method`, there are quite a number common cases where such algorithm will fail. So, it might not appropriate to consider them as `exception`

How about 3rd approach, returning `Double.NaN`? Is that consider a good practice?

Here's the source code for your reference.

https://github.com/yccheok/xirr/blob/master/src/org/yccheok/quant/XIRR.java#L56

Note that, there isn't any error checking being implemented yet. So, `err` might never further reduced, and the method might go into infinity loop.

Comment: `Double.NaN` would be very less common and might not be expected by all the developers to handle it

Comment: No, definitely not a good practice. Throw an exception. Exceptions are exceptional. They shouldn't affect performance. If a failed computation is the norm, return an object indicating the success or failure, and containing the value in case of success. You're probably pre-optimizing, and premature optimization is the root of all evil. Returning NaN is certainly evil.

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"...  The cleanest approach would be to throw an exception.  If you expect to run this routine billions of times, so that performance is that significant, do whatever is fastest without worrying about "good practice", and add enough comments so that other programmers are aware of what you're doing.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi, I update my view point on why I avoid using `exception` besides performance consideration.

Comment: A fourth approach: Add an input argument that is an object containing a boolean field to indicate success or failure, and have callers check that.  A `boolean[]` may work, where the array is expected to have length 1.  This is also not "good practice" but may have acceptable performance and may be a little better than `NaN`.

Comment: So, as I said, if failures constitute a significant part of the results, then return an object indicating success or failure, and containing the value or the explanation of the error.

Comment: "Makes code look messy"... If the result needs to be checked by callers, then they will need to add a check, and any such check will look somewhat messy.  The advantage of exceptions is that if the caller omits the check (because it's too messy), an exception will not let the program continue with bad data, while a `NaN` will get involved in computations, meaning any error or incorrect output will happen a lot later making the omission more difficult to track down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the practice of using a special return value for exceptional situations goes against the grain with Java's way of informing the caller about exceptional situations. To that end, strategies #1 and #3 are equivalent, because both of them result in caller code like this:

```
// This could be double or Double
double res = Newtons_method(pmt, guess);
// This could be res==null check or Double.isNaN(res) call
if (!checkResult(res)) {
    // Do something else
}
// Do regular processing
```

This is error-prone, because inevitably somebody will forget to do the check, causing errors down the road. This tends to happen more when method calls are nested, as in

```
double res = doStuff(Newtons_method(pmt1, guess), Newtons_method(pmt2, guess));
```

An incorrect result makes it into parameters of the next-level function call, forcing either an argument exception (if the coder is very good about his argument checking) or a hard to debug error down the road.

Your strategy #2 is better, because callers cannot simply "forget" to catch the exception: they would have to either catch and process it, or add `throws` to their own method.

Comment: For best performance, override Exception's fillInStackTrace method to do nothing.  Do that, and even throwing the exception is likely to be faster than checking a return value.

Comment: And for even better performance, keep a static Exception handy and always throw that, saving the cost of creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that combines the safety-net advantage of exceptions, but doesn't force the caller to use them to check for success or failure. It also doesn't have the cost of throwing an exception each time the result is a failure, if the caller doesn't want this cost:

```
public Result compute(...) { ... }

public interface Result {
    /**
     * Returns true if the computation was successful
     */
    boolean isSuccessFul();

    /**
     * Returns the computed value if successful.
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the computation failed - you could use another exception here if you prefer
     */ 
    double getValue();

    /**
     * Gets the reason for the failure, is the computation has failed.
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the computation succeeded
     */
    String getFailureReason();
}

class Success implements Result {
    private final double value;

    public Success(double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSuccessFul() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFailureReason() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("The computation was successful");
    }
}

class Failure implements Result {
    private final String reason;

    public Failure(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSuccessFul() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public double getValue() {
        throw new IllegalStateException(reason);
    }

    @Override
    public String getFailureReason() {
        return reason;
    }
}
```

That way, callers assuming that the result is successful will do

```
double result = compute().getValue();
```

and will get a meaningful exception if the result was a failure.

And people who test the result will be able to do it without having any performance loss due to exceptions:

```
Result r = compute();
if (r.isSuccessful()) {
    double value = r.getValue();
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

This is basically similar as returning null, except the code is much more self-explanatory, the caller has much less chance of forgetting to test the failure case, and gets a meaningful exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people use Double.NaN in a similar manner, and I've never heard anyone saying it was bad practice to do that. You might want to put in the methods Javadocs that you use that approach though.